# Find the product of the number of letters "o" in all the words "google", "gooogle",... in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to write a static function **int count Google Product(String)**, which returns the product of the number of letters "o" in all the words "google", "gooogle", ... in a string.

- P38.countGoogleProduct("google gooogle") == 6
- P38.countGoogleProduct("google gogle gooogle gooogle") == 18 == 2*3*3
- P38.countGoogleProduct("microsoft gogle") == 1
- P38.countGoogleProduct("microsoft amazon facebooooook") == 1
- P38.countGoogleProduct("googleing") == 1
- P38.countGoogleProduct("googlee") == 1
- P38.countGoogleProduct("  google   google  ") == 4 == 2*2
- P38.countGoogleProduct("googlegoogle") == 1

The answer is guaranteed to be no more than 2*10^9.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class P38 {
    static int countGoogleProduct(String s) {
        boolean f = false;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(( +goo+gle +)+( +goo+gle +))|( +goo+gle +)|(.*( +goo+gle +).*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            f = true;
        } else {
            f = false;
        }
        if (f) {
            int c = 1;
            boolean g = false;
            String ns = new String();
            Pattern np = Pattern.compile("o+");
            Matcher nm = np.matcher(s);
            while (nm.find()) {
                ns = nm.group();
                c = c * ns.length();
            }
            return c;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("...");
        System.out.println(countGoogleProduct(s));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work on some tests like
" googlegoogle google " == 8 (right anwer 2)
"googlegoogle google" == 1 (right anwer 2)
Could you tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: Why should `googlegoogle` be `1`? Why is `googlee` `1`?

Comment: Why does your second id = 18 = 233?

Comment: How is `P38.countGoogleProduct("microsoft amazon facebooooook") == 1`? It does not have a word, `google`.

Comment: I think I understand the preconditions: basically anything will be a `1` - and if it matches `g(o{2,})gle` then the value is equal to the number of o.

Comment: @NomadMaker I suspect it means `18 == 2*3*3`, like one of the examples below that says `4 == 2*2` , the first one became an italic 3

Comment: @luk2302 that can't be a correct precondition because of `("googlee") == 1` in OPs questions.

Comment: @Eugene the last e makes it not match the pattern, same logic for very last example.

Comment: @luk2302 if you don't mind what do you think should `microsoft gooogle` report? `1` if you ask me

Comment: @Eugene 3 - similar to the 2nd example

Comment: @luk2302 but then this somehow makes 5th example weird then. To me, if there is a single match of `g(o+)gle` then the result should be `1`

Comment: @Eugene no, just split each word and then check if each word follows the pattern - googleing does not => 1

Comment: @luk2302 oh darn, then this makes it soo much easier! thank you for getting my understanding straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to capture all the `o`s in a capture group, so that you can find the captured string's length, and multiply that. Also, use `\b` to match the word boundaries, so you only match `go+gle` when it is surrounded by non-word characters.

```
static int countGoogleProduct(String s) {
    boolean f = false;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bg(o+)gle\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int product = 1;
    while (m.find()) {
        product *= m.group(1).length();
    }
    return product;
}
```

You didn't say what should happen for `ggle`. Should I count that as a 1 or 0? The above code will count it as a 1. If you want to count it as a 0, replace the quantifier `+` with `*`.

Comment: Pretty sure `ggle` should be `1` as well, same as `gogle` or `lalala` - it is just not a google product but should not zero out the multiplication either.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it greatly by splitting the string on whitespace and then processing each part. While processing each part, calculate the sum of `o` in each part and multiply the same with `product` where `product` is the variable initialized with `1` before you process the parts of the string.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] arr = { "google gooogle", "google gogle gooogle gooogle", "microsoft gogle",
                "microsoft amazon facebooooook", "googleing", "googlee", " google google ", "googlegoogle" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + countGoogleProduct(s));
        }
    }

    static int countGoogleProduct(String str) {
        int product = 1;

        // Convert to a single case and then split on whitespace
        String[] arr = str.toLowerCase().split("\\s+");

        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s.matches("g(o{2,})gle")) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
                    if (ch == 'o') {
                        sum++;
                    }
                }
                product *= sum;
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
google gooogle => 6
google gogle gooogle gooogle => 18
microsoft gogle => 1
microsoft amazon facebooooook => 1
googleing => 1
googlee => 1
 google google  => 4
googlegoogle => 1
```

The regex, `g(o{2,})gle` means `g` followed by [two or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) `o` followed by `gle`. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/ydK3Gk/1) for a demo of the regex.

Comment: What is the output for `"microsoft amazon facebooooook"`!? I agree that the solution can probably be a lot simpler and not rely on regex but this solution is too simple.

Comment: Oh...is that also a case? I wrote the answer after reading the requirement, `I need to write a static function int count Google Product(String), which returns the product of the number of letters "o" in all the words "google", "gooogle", ... in a string.`. Thanks for letting me know. I will go through all the example strings in the question now and will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @luk2302 for the valuable feedback. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int count(String in) {

    return new Scanner(in)
        .findAll("(?<!\\w)g(o+)gle(?=(\\s|$))")
        .mapToInt(mr -> mr.group(1).length())
        .reduce(Math::multiplyExact)
        .orElse(1);
}
```

- find all occurrences of `g`, followed by any number of repeating `o`, followed by `gle`, followed by either : a space or the end of the String (`(?=(\\s|$))`)
- at the same time the previous match must not start with any word character (`(?<!\\w)`)
- from the previous match find how many those `o` where repeating.
- reduce those using `Math::multiplyExact`